# Periscope-like application architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, wowza, azure-media-services

Are there any cloud services that will greatly simplify Periscope-like application development? We also need to record (archive) live streams for further playback on mobile devices.

I see that many well-known cloud services like Azure Media Services or AWS Elemental Media Live have a low default limit for maximum number of live channels, like 5-10.

Answer (score 0):

See a response to a similar question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ea22c9bc-0858-4750-8951-921e9856e6e5/interesting-about-ios-live-broadcast-sdk?forum=MediaServices). Others have tried using products from Wowza, building and managing their own deployment of VMs running their streaming engine.